# symlinking and running an installation command

Tags: linux, installation, symlink

In the installation guide of some soft, user is told to run this

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft* /opt/local/bin
```

Is this command dangerous ? Should /opt/local/bin be prevented from calling something else tha n itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command does few things

- sudo gives root permissions to the 'ln' binary
- ln is instructed to go through all files matching pattern /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft*
- for every such file it tries to create symbolic link in /opt/local/bin directory
- this created symbolic link will have the same name as the file just being processed

Your first question is, is it dangerous? Most probably not, there are few things which might go wrong

- your $PATH environment contains some strange directory, so instead of calling /usr/bin/ln (as was the original intention I believe) you wold be tricked into calling some different executable. For example if your PATH=.:/tmp:/usr/bin, 'ln' is first searched in your current directory, then in /tmp and then in /usr/bin. And it's called with superuser permissions ...
- there are no such files as /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft* . In such case ln will create symbolic link '/opt/local/bin/somsoft*' (including the star in it's name). That's probably not what you wanted
- /opt/local/bin already contains the files with the same names as /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft* . In such case ln will not create new files there (is it good or bad? that is the question)
- You don't have /opt/local/bin . In such cases there are several ways of how the command fails (depending whether you have /opt/local directory and how many files match the pattern /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft*)

Your second question does not make much sense. /opt/local/bin is a directory, and directory can't "call" anything. So it can't be prevented to do so. If you ask whether the symbolic links should be created there, I would say why not. The whole idea behind the command is to

- install somesoft into special directory so that you won't pollute your /usr/bin or any other common directory
- to be able to run the commands without the need of specifying every time full path /opt/local/somesoft/somsoft... you may want to create symbolic links in /opt/local/bin. And make sure that your /opt/local/bin is in your directory.